# oracle between clause inclusive format HH24:MI

Tags: sql, oracle, format, to-date

My query looks something like:

```
select *
from mytable
where date_field between to_date(#from#, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI')
   and to_date(#to#, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI')
```

As an example:

```
if from = 2012/07/18 00:00 and
   to   = 2012/07/18 00:09
```

will this include records with timestamp `2012/07/18 00:09:01` to `2012/07/18 00:09:59`?

or should I change the statement to:

```
select *
from mytable
where date_field >= to_date(#from#, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI')
   < to_date(#to#, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI')
```

here substituting from : 2012/07/18 00:00 & to: 2012/07/18 00:10 should give me all records with timestamp between midnight & 9M59S past midnight, which is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The between clause accepts **both** the interval bounds.
I suggest the second option to you

```
select *
from mytable
where date_field >= to_date(#from#, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI')
   < to_date(#to#, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI')
```

You may find [this article](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WhyNumberingShouldStartAtZero) interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the date portion of the `DATE` elements, since both 00:09:01 and 00:09:59 come after your "to" time of 00:09:00, no, this query will not include those records.

If you want to include those records, you will need to extend your "to" time to 00:10:00 or `TRUNC` your records's timestamps to the nearest minute.

Edit:

If your from and to are only accurate to the minute, I'd do this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM mytable
 WHERE date_field >= to_date(#from#, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI') 
   AND date_field <  to_date(#to#,   'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI') + 1/24/60/60 /* 1 minute */
```

And make sure you use bind variable for from and to.  Is this ColdFusion? If so, use `cfqueryparam`.

Comment: Since the dates are inclusive, if I use 00:10:00 wouldn't this include 10? I want to exclude it!

Comment: Correct, it would. BETWEEN is shorthand for "start <= foo and foo <= end".

Answer (score 0):

The date conversion is going to convert the values into dates, which contain all date elements.  You have not specified seconds in the strings, so these will become 0.

In other words, the range  ":01" - ":59" is not included.

Since you are working with strings and the strings have date elements in the proper order for comparison, why not do string compares instead:

```
where to_char(datefield, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI') between #from# and #to#
```

I think this does exactly what you want, without fiddling around with date arithmetic.

You can also change the statement as you propose, by incrementing the #to# column and using "<" instead of between.

Comment: Note that would likely prevent the use of an index on `date_field`.

Comment: This can be handled by creating function based indexes in Oracle . . . http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/statements_5012.htm.  By the way, you would have the same problem with rounding the date or doing other date arithmetic.

Comment: We do want to use the index as this call needs to be performant!

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Oracle will only skip the index if the function is applied to the field from the table, not if it's applied to the other part (?) of the predicate.

Comment: @eaolson . . . Another solution was to truncate the date to the nearest minute.  That has the same problem with the index.  Creating a function-based index or using "<" are the best solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM mytable
 WHERE date_field between to_date(#from#, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI')
   AND to_date(#to#||':59', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
```